# Single-Select query doesn´t show the values but it works

Tags: jasperserver

We are using *JasperReports Server Community Edition 5.5* and have a problem with a Single-Select Query. The problem is that the Input Control list doesn´t show any values in the list but you can see the spaces for each value. The list must return two values and it shows two spaces but no the value in it. The weird thing is that the report works. We are connecting to a SQL Server 2012 Database and the column being returned is of datatype "Date".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I forgot to add a value in the "Visible Columns" property.